# Как сделать функционал подтверждения номера телефона?

Tags: веб-программирование

вопрос таков. Есть сайт с формой заявки. Пользователь заполняет поля, и на номер телефона который он указал приходит код подтверждения . Пользователь водит и если все правильно идет отправка на почту? Какой подход использовать и какие ресурсы ( в том числе отправка и прием сообщений ) задействовать ?

Comment: интересует реализация на каком-то конкретном языке?

Comment: Что за проект? Какой язык? Какой стек технологий?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, проблема в том что этот проект должен был быть чистом HTML  / CSS / JS с простой формой для отправки. Но почему то решили что нужно подтверждения телефона. Я почти уверен что имея лишь чистую верстку такую реализацию нельзя сделать, но все же уточнить на stackoverflow.

Comment: не уверен, но вроде бы backend язык нужен :)

Comment: @Danielqwaqwaqwa можно если только найдете какой-то сторонний сервис. Что-то на подобие этого http://tarampampam.github.io/jquery.textmistake/ . А так да, надо писать отправку на стороне сервера

Comment: И то не совсем понятно будет как проверить код, если использовать сторонний сервис

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin Уточнил сейчас, требуется манипуляции на php ,back end

Comment: @Danielqwaqwaqwa могу только на словах описать механизм т.к. с php не работал.

Comment: Да, php или другой язык на стороне сервера необходим. Просто потому, что если из js кода воспользоваться сервисом отправки СМС то значит в коде будет пароль к этому сервису и кто нибудь от вашего имени и за ваш счет начнет рассылать СМС-спам. А так вам надо: 1. записать в базу данных (или еще куда нибудь) информацию  о пользователе. 2. сгенерировать случайный код, так же записать его в БД. 3. С использованием стороннего сервиса (например sms.ru) и их API отправить СМС. 4. Запросить код у клиента на сайте, при вводе отправить на сервер и сравнить с сохраненным

Comment: На самом деле чуть сложнее, желательно контролировать время жизни отосланных кодов (если необходимо). Предусмотреть защиту от слишком частой отправки кодов. Предусмотреть защиту от отправки запросов на проверку каким нибудь ботом (например капчу поставить), иначе кто нибудь сможет быстро слить ваш бюджет на отправку СМС